# android Runtime Exception

Tags: android

When i run my android application it shows an exception "android runtime exception" with a message "Error: thread attach failed". it happens before the execution of "OnCreate" mathod of main class. what will be reason for that error?? anybody please help.

Comment: need some hint of the code or the logcat error log...

Comment: 10-22 11:08:52.085: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20832): ERROR: thread attach failed
10-22 11:08:52.095: INFO/dalvikvm(20832): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-22 11:08:53.995: WARN/dalvikvm(95): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
10-22 11:08:54.005: INFO/ActivityManager(95): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ars.application/.LightVas }
10-22 11:08:54.075: INFO/ActivityManager(95): Start proc com.ars.application for activity com.ars.application/.LightVas: